# Can I still export Rock Band 1 songs to Rock Band 2?

Tags: xbox-360, rock-band

I have the physical copies of all rock band games for Xbox 360. I am just wondering if the license to export the rock band 1 songs is still available because I keep going to export the songs and it keeps saying “This item is no longer available.” So I don’t know whether if it is a license expire or a glitch with my game or system. Can someone help me with a possible solution?

Comment: I see you asked about this in that other question that's nearly a decade old.  At this point you may have a better chance reaching out to Xbox support directly.